# Varnish and WordPress stuck at wp-login.php

Tags: wordpress, varnish

I am trying to fix some stuff with some website and came across a big issue which I am really stuck on now and can't move on. 
The problem is like this after I do enter right username + password and hit on login at mydomain.com/wp-admin/ it will redirect me to mydomain.com/wp-login.php with a blank page. I have been trying for hours now and came with no solution.

I tried

- this [VarnishAndWordpress](https://www.varnish-cache.org/trac/wiki/VarnishAndWordpress)
- to disable all plugins
- to enable some redirect plugins
- this [wordpress-wp-admin-redirecting-to-wp-login-php-when-logged-in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31207117/wordpress-wp-admin-redirecting-to-wp-login-php-when-logged-in)
- to add new users delete users
- and I tried to replace wp-admin and wp-includes with a fresh copy.
  unfortunately all didn't work. And though if after I do login I change the URL to mydomain.com/wp-admin/ it will take me to the dashboard but I really need the redirect to work :(
  Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the HTTP status code of the blank page? Is it 200, 500...? If it's 500, do you have a error_log file or Apache/nginx errors log? If it's 200, what are the HTTP headers of the response? Have you tried to disable Varnish and login back to see if it's still blank?

Comment: enable wp debug mode and see what it says

Comment: @santerref its only blank no error not in nginx nor in php5-fpm

Comment: @crystalwill enabled it nothing to show

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out to be a Theme problem. changing the theme fixed the problem.